# levenshtein distance implementation with path reconstruction asymptotic complexity

Tags: c, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

can someone help me on define asymptotic complexity of these two C functions ?

1) Simple function which outputs the levenshtein distance of two given strings

```
int levenshtein_distance( char *s1 , char *s2 ,matrix_t  matrix )
{
    int options[3];
    int len_s1 = strlen(s1);
    int len_s2 = strlen(s2);
    int res;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    for(i = 1 ; i < len_s1 ; i++ )
    {
        for(j = 1 ; j < len_s2 ; j++)
        {
            options[MATCH]  = matrix[i-1][j-1].cost + match(s1[i],s2[j]);
            options[INSERT] = matrix[i][j-1].cost + 1;
            options[DELETE] = matrix[i-1][j].cost + 1;

            matrix[i][j].cost = options[MATCH];
            matrix[i][j].parent = MATCH;

            for (k=INSERT; k<=DELETE; k++)
                if (options[k] < matrix[i][j].cost)
                {
                    matrix[i][j].cost = options[k];
                    matrix[i][j].parent = k;
                }
        }

    }

    res = matrix[(len_s1-1)][(len_s2 -1)].cost;
    return res;
}
```

2) Recursive method which reconstructs the path of edit operations

```
void reconstruct_path(char *s1, char *s2 , int i, int j , matrix_t matrix)
{
    if(matrix[i][j].parent == -1) return;


    if (matrix[i][j].parent == MATCH)
    {
        reconstruct_path(s1,s2,i-1,j-1,matrix);
        match_out(s1, s2, i, j);
        return;
    }

    if (matrix[i][j].parent == INSERT)
    {
        reconstruct_path(s1,s2,i,j-1,matrix);
        insert_out(s2, j);
        return;
    }

    if (matrix[i][j].parent == DELETE)
    {
        reconstruct_path(s1,s2,i-1,j,matrix);
        delete_out(s1 , i);
        return;
    }
}
```

match is

```
int match(char a , char b)
{
    if(a == b) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

match_out , insert_out and delete_out only perform a printf for each call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first function is clearly O(m * n) where m = strlen(s1) and n = strlen(s2).  The inner-most loop with the if-condition is executed 3 * m * n times, hence O(m * n).

The second function is O(i+j)  (It is unclear what relationship there is between i,j and strlen(s1) and strlen(s2) based on the provided definitions).  Note that on each recursive call, we presumably match on one of the provided conditions, and either i or j or both are decremented.  Either this results in an error when i or j fall below 0, or it terminates before then.  Also note that for a particular recursive call, it only executes one of the paths.  In the worst case, i falls to 0 matching DELETE i times, then j falls to 0 matching INSERT j times and then you terminate.

Comment: The order is this: i = strlen(s1) , j = strlen(s2). Can you explain the reasoning behind O(i+j) ?

Comment: Sure.  In the worst case, (ignoring the possible semantics of the matrix, and looking strictly at the possible code-paths), you can match something like: DELETE, DELETE, ... DELETE i times and then INSERT, INSERT, ... INSERT j times (interleaving of INSERT and DELETE operations would also be possible).  Note that each time, you decrement either i or j, and you cannot do more than i DELETE operations or j INSERT operations.  So, i DELETES plus j INSERTS becomes an upper bound.